# Writing to disk without using java.io

Tags: java, groovy

Suppose the use of `java.io` has been blocked. What are some alternative ways of writing, say a simple `"Hello World!"` text file to disk, using Java/Groovy language features?

Comment: Can you eludicate what "java.io has been blocked" means? How was it blocked? `SecurityManager`? Using what `Permission`s?

Comment: @icza Through the use of Groovy's SecureASTCustomizer, blocking all java.io imports.

Comment: Can you confirm if `java.nio.Files` is allowed?

Comment: the java.nio.Files worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If only `java.io` has been blocked (you said `java.io` imports are blocked), you can use the `java.nio` to write to files.

Look at the central [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class. In `java.nio` files/folders are represented with `java.nio.Path` objects which is also part of the `java.nio` package (and not `java.io`).

Example writing `"Hello World!"` into a text file to the disk:

```
Files.write(Paths.get("/your/folder/text.txt"),
    "Hello World!".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

// Or
Files.write(Paths.get("/your/folder/text.txt"),
    Arrays.asList("Hello World!"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Nope. Java nio internally uses java.io.

Comment: The question is how `java.io` was blocked. Questioner said `java.io` imports are blocked in which case this would work.

Comment: It won't work, because java NIO uses java.io. If java.io is blocked, java NIO can't work.

Comment: I'll try to explain it better: The `Files` class has `java.io` `import`s and makes calls to `java.io.OutputStream`. if `java.io` imports are blocked, the `java.nio.Files` class can't work.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. It is still unclear for me if the restirction applies only to "user" code or to the standard lib too. In the first case this wouldn't work, in the latter case it would. This needs clarification from the questioner.

Answer (score 3):

JNI to talk directly to the underlying OS API.

Comment: Nope. JNI loading internally uses java.io.